# iPhone - numberOfRowsInSection error with array count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsinteger

I am getting the following error if the @"Comments" array is 0 and the other two are 1 or greater.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

This is populating the `self.items` array.

How can I account for the fact that some of the `self.notification` (Comments in this case) arrays may be null and still have my code run without throwing this type of error?

```
NSDictionary *commentsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.notification.Comments forKey:@"Comments"];
NSDictionary *likesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.notification.Likes forKey:@"Likes"];
NSDictionary *friendsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.notification.Likes forKey:@"Friends"];

self.items = [NSMutableArray array];

[self.items addObject:commentsDict];
[self.items addObject:likesDict];
[self.items addObject:friendsDict];
```

This is the code where it fails:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.items objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *array = nil;

    if (section == 0) {
        array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Comments"]; // 0 count
    } else if (section == 1) {
        array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Likes"]; // 1 count or greater
    } else {
        array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Friends"]; // 1 count or greater
    }

    return [array count];
}
```

Comment: Can you tell use more about your data structure? What really contains items? Shouldn't you simply return [[self.items objectAtIndex:section] count] ?

Comment: can you post the exception message? as the real exception is somewhat difficult message, but may it contain any hint or useful information to identify the error

Comment: You having empty array.possibly your array got released.

Comment: Updated original question code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with my `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;` as I was only referencing the Comments array instead of the other two when changing the section header.

Answer (score 2):

put a `NSLog(@"Array: %@", self.items);` in front of your code and you will see that the array is indeed empty.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get an object by an index that is not there. Perhaps the `self.items` array doesn't have an object for each section index. Fromt the error message it looks like `self.items` is actually empty (zero objects).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have too many sections defined (more than the number of items in self.items):

Then this would fail:

```
[self.items objectAtIndex:section]
```

Answer (score 1):

To work this out, you'll need to look at how you set `self.items` and how you implemented `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`.

Either `self.items` is releasing the array early or how you're returning the number of sections is independent of `self.items`.